# CodeIgniter session not writing to the DB after PHP version upgrade to 7.2.10

Tags: php, mysql, session, codeigniter-3, php-7.2

I upgraded my PHP version from 5.6 to 7.2.10 and suddenly writting session data to MySQL database stopped working (the session table is empty). I also upgraded CodeIgniter version to 3.1.9 (the system folder only) but this didn't help. I think the problem may be in some configurations for PHP (or MySQL) because the first thing I have to do was to change autostart session in php.ini.
When I retrieve value from $this->config->item('sess_driver') I get "database". When I retrieve values from $this->session I get:

```
object(CI_Session)[14]
  public 'userdata' => null
  protected '_driver' => string 'files' (length=5)
  protected '_config' => null
  protected '_sid_regexp' => null
```

That is strange because in older PHP version I get "database" as _driver value. It looks like the session data are stored in files - when I ask for $this->session->has_userdata('id') I get the correct value but it should be saved in database session table but it is not.
This is my part of config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Does somebody meet my problem or know the solution? Thanks

Comment: do you have the Session table in the database with the correct (required) fields?

Comment: Yes, of course I do. Otherwise I would get a DB error.

Comment: I think they changed the default database to MariaDB

Comment: mhh. I think this question should be asked or maybe even posted as an issue at the CodeIgniter GitHub repo

Comment: I'm using CI v3.1.9 and PHP v7.2.10 and it works fine. Is there a config file in an environment folder that isn't the one you show? That's one (only?) logical reason that `protected '_driver'` would say `'files'` but the config you show is set to 'database'.

Comment: @DFriend Everything happened when I upgrade my wampserver to 3.1.4. Maybe I should change something in php.ini or ...?

Comment: Upgraded from what version to 3.1.4?

Answer (score -1):

I might suggest you solution.

1. Go to codeigniter website.
2. download lastest version of codeiginter.
3. extract it.
4. make rename system folder to something else in existing project.
5. paste new system folder and you done it.